# Add HTML Canvas Offset Text Outline

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I add an offset outline to a text in an HTML canvas like in this example:

[image]

here's what I got so far:

```
var canvas = /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ (
    document.getElementById("myCanvas")
);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Function to draw text with an offset outline
function drawTextWithOutline(
    text,
    x,
    y,
    textColor,
    outlineColor,
    outlineWidth
) {
    // Draw the outline
    const font = "80px Dancing Script";
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = outlineWidth;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);

    // Draw the text
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

// Call the function with desired parameters
drawTextWithOutline("Hello, World!", 50, 100, "red", "blue", 20);
```

[image]

how do i remove the fill and retain only the outline like in the example?

Comment: Draw the outline twice. One smaller than the other (less line width). For the smaller one, draw it white or whatever color to hollow it out (to match the background, if desired). Then draw the text as you have in red.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I did is when you draw the outline, **draw another outline that matches the background color and has a smaller outline width.**

```js
var canvas = /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ (
    document.getElementById("myCanvas")
);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Function to draw text with an offset outline
function drawTextWithOutline(
    text,
    x,
    y,
    textColor,
    outlineColor,
    outlineWidth
) {
    // Draw the outline
    const font = "40px Dancing Script";
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = outlineWidth;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
    ctx.lineWidth = outlineWidth - 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);

    // Draw the text
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

// Call the function with desired parameters
drawTextWithOutline("Hello, World!", 50, 100, "red", "blue",20);
```

```css
canvas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = 'myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: OP said s/he tried this already and was unsatisfied with the result. (for some reason the comment was deleted). It's exactly what I suggested he do. Yours looks pretty good! ... But OP probably wants it to be exactly as the source.